# How would I write something into a .txt file and then copy it as a String or Array later?

Tags: java, java-io

I am working on a project for school that has me doing my own research on syntax and other things related to the project.

I already have the bulk code, the idea is an index of people living in an apartment building, which floor, and in which room. This will also save the rent/payment of water and electricity.

I have a way to store these as multidimensional arrays. I can't figure out how to copy the code into a .txt file.

This is an example not using the arrays e.g.

```
package buildings

public class main{
    public static String name = "James";
    public static int buildingName = 1;
    public static int floor = 2;
    public static int room = 1;
    public static float rent = 250.99;
}
```

How would I possibly put these variables into a text file, and how would I be able to reference them later on when running the program again?

Answer (score 0):

Using java 8 to achieve it as follows.

```
public class WriteClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Person jack = new Person("Jack", 1, 2, 1, 250.99);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(jack.toString());
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString().concat("/persons.txt"));
            System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            Files.write(path, list);
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(jack);
    }

    static class Person {
        String name;
        int buildingNum;
        int floorNum;
        int roomNum;
        double rentCost;

        public Person(String name, int buildingNum, int floorNum, int roomNum, double rentCost) {
            this.name = name;
            this.buildingNum = buildingNum;
            this.floorNum = floorNum;
            this.roomNum = roomNum;
            this.rentCost = rentCost;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("{name: %s, building No.: %d, floor No.: %d, room No.: %d, rent cost: %.2f",
                    name, buildingNum, floorNum, roomNum, rentCost);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output of the file will be as:

```
{name: Jack, building No.: 1, floor No.: 2, room No.: 1, rent cost: 250.99}
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify where the file path will go? From what I can see, it would only make a new file every time you ran it.

Comment: A specified path and then write to by appending? What’s your plan?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, first, you need to think of an absolute format in which you will store your variables. 
    In this case for arrays, I used this `!var1!var2!var3` and then use a special character to symbolize the next row in the array, for example, a ^
    so a 2d array like this

```
[0,0,0]
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
```

would look like this in the file `0!0!0!^1!2!3!^4!5!6!` and so when you read from the file containing this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File("src\\vars\\array1")); 
String file = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
scanner.close();`
//you do
String[] arrays = file.split("^");`
//and then
String[][] test = new int[arrays.length][arrays.length];` 
Assuming it's a square array, if
//not, just either remember how long it is or count throught the file first
for(int x = 0; x < arrays.length; x++)
test[x] = arrays[x].split("!");
//and then finally
int[][] finalArray = new int[test.length][test[0].length];
for(int x = 0; x < arrays.length; x++)
   for(int y = 0; y < arrays.length; y++)
      finalArray[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(test[x][y]);
```

and to write to a file

```
File newfile = new File("src\\vars\\array1");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newfile, true));
out.write("Print to the file using your format :)");`
```

Sorry for the whole thing in code brackets, stacks editor was getting angry at me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider using POJO(Plain Old Java Object) in this case. Store each property of people as an attribute of the class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int buildingNumber;
  private int floor;
  private int room;
  private double rent;
}
```

I would give you 3 options.

**Option 1**

1) Create a custom string for each person which stores all properties of Person separated by some common Character. ie

```
Person p = new Person("ABC",1, 4,2,1250);
String splitter = "*_*"
String deserializedString = p.getName() + splitter + p.getBuildingNumber() + splitter + p.getFloor() + splitter + p.getRoom() + splitter + p.getRent();
```

That would create a string like:

```
ABC*_*1*_*4*_*2*_*1250
```

2) Once you have a string for all the people, store that list in the File you want.

3) To read back from file, read all the lines from file one by one.

4) One you have one line, split the string with `*_*`, that would give you String[] which you can use to re-generate Person class.

**Option 2**

In this case, rather than storing Person information in plain text in the file, you can write java object in a file.

For that, you will have to create one wrapper class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class BuildingPeopleData {
List<Person> allPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
}
```

Store information of all the person in the above list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   BuildingPeopleData data = new BuildingPeopleData();
   data.setAllPeople(listOfPeople) // create listOfPeople list first. I have intentionally not explained that here. 
   // Code to Write data object in file 
   // Code to read data back from file 
   // Example tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/
}
```

**Option 3**

Use Third-party library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). 
Jackson library lets us convert Java Pojo into String which will represent your data in JSON format like below:

```
{"Name":"ABC","BuildingNumber":1,"Floor":4,"room":2,"rent":1250}
```

Store those strings in file.

And when you want to read them back, read them as a string from file.

Then use Jackson library to convert that json string to an instance of Person class.